# C++: Update to memory location using pointer is lost

Tags: c++, pointers

The two main classes in the code are TestVm and TestLocalQueue. LocalQueue holds a queue and provides put method to add contents to the queue .

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class ERBaseEventType {
public:
    ERBaseEventType();
    string dynamic;
    void setDynamic(string );
    string getDynamic();
    };
ERBaseEventType::ERBaseEventType() {
}

void ERBaseEventType::setDynamic(string ndynamic){
    dynamic=ndynamic;
}
string ERBaseEventType::getDynamic(){
    return dynamic;
}

class BaseEventType : public ERBaseEventType {
public:
    BaseEventType();

};
BaseEventType::BaseEventType() {
}
class ControlCommand : public ERBaseEventType{
public:
    ControlCommand();

};
ControlCommand::ControlCommand() {

}
class LocalQueue {
    // static const int ENDLEN =100;
      string name;
      ERBaseEventType * queue[100];            // holds the queue
        int  head, tail;             // indices of head and tail
    bool lock;
    public:
        void init();                // initialize
             // store
        void put(ControlCommand * );
        void print();


};
void LocalQueue::init()
{
    head = tail = 0;
    cout<<"tail value  is "<<tail<<endl;
    cout<<"head value is "<<head<<endl;

}

void LocalQueue::put(ControlCommand * mb )
{

    if(tail+1==head || (tail+1==100 && !head)) {
    cout << "Queue is full\n";
    lock=false;
        return;
    }

    if(tail == 100)
        tail = 0; // cycle around
    queue[tail] =   mb;

    cout << "Added to the queue tail is "<<tail<<endl;
    cout << "Address is  "<<queue+tail<<endl;
        tail++;

}
void LocalQueue::print(){
    std::cout<<"\nprint  :";
    std::cout<<tail;
    for(int q=0;q<tail;q++){
        cout << "\nAddress is  "<<queue+q<<endl;
        string ntdynamicContext=queue[q]->getDynamic();
        std::cout<<ntdynamicContext;


    }
}


class TestLocalQueue {
private:
    LocalQueue * localQueue;
public:
    TestLocalQueue(LocalQueue *);
    void putMsg();
    virtual ~TestLocalQueue();
};
TestLocalQueue::TestLocalQueue(LocalQueue * lq) {
    localQueue=lq;
}
void TestLocalQueue::putMsg(){
    ControlCommand * cd =new ControlCommand;
    cd->setDynamic("alpha");
    localQueue->put(cd);
    localQueue->print(); //-----> prints the content
   // delete cd;
}
TestLocalQueue::~TestLocalQueue() {

}
class TestVM {
public:
    static LocalQueue localQueue;
    void addMessage();
    void print();
    TestVM();
    virtual ~TestVM();
};
LocalQueue TestVM::localQueue;
TestVM::TestVM() {
    localQueue.init();
    cout<<"localQueue initialized  \n"<<endl;
}
void TestVM::addMessage(){
    TestLocalQueue t(&localQueue);

    t.putMsg();
}
void TestVM::print(){
    localQueue.print();
}
TestVM::~TestVM() {
}

int main(){
    TestVM v;
    v.addMessage();
    cout<<"\nprinting from main  \n"<<endl;
    v.print();   //-----> does not print the content
}
```

Problem:

I pass a reference to "localQueue" from TestVM to TestLocalQueue and  add contents to localQueue (putMsg()) using that reference. Within TestLocalQueue i can access the added contents when i call print putMsg(). But when i try to access localqueue from TestVM (as i have marked in the code) i cannot get the contents.

Sorry for too much code. I have tried to simplify it.

Comment: Add some code that shows the problem, instead of describing the problem. Preferably make a single file with a `main()` that someone else could run to see the problem.

Comment: Hi, i have added one file now with main when i run
this line in void TestLocalQueue::putMsg()
localQueue->print(); prints the content

whereas in main v.print(); does not display the content

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting a comment. Bear in mind that this is not a forum.

Comment: **-1**, to much code. Add some code which generates problem and delete code which is never called when launching code generating problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad:

```
void TestLocalQueue::putMsg(){
    ControlCommand cc;
    cc.setDynamic("target");
    cout<<"Setting Dynamic context \n"<<endl;
   localQueue->put(&cc );
```

The `localQueue->put` function stores the pointer you give it into the queue.
However `cc`'s lifetime is only for the duration of the `putMsg` function, so when this function exits you will have a dangling pointer.

To fix this you could either make the queue store copies of objects, or you could dynamically allocate `cc`.